# At level up, can a sorcerer learn spells of a level granted by slots he has from any class?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, multi-classing, sorcerer

The sorcerer's spells known feature says:

> You know two 1st-level spells of your choice from the sorcerer spell list.
>  The **Spells Known** column of **Table: The Sorcerer** shows when you learn
>   more sorcerer spells of your choice. Each of these spells must be of a
>   level for which you have spell slots. For instance, when you reach 3rd
>   level in this class, you can learn one new spell of 1st or 2nd level.

The part I'm concerned with is the following: *"Each of these spells must be of a level for which you have spell slots."*  The wording, unfortunately, assumes single-class characters only.

We know from the multiclass rules that if a character is multiclassed between two casting classes, that spell slots are granted based on the following:

> **Spell Slots:** You determine your available spell slots by adding
>   together all your levels in the bard, cleric, druid, sorcerer, and
>   wizard classes, and half your levels (rounded down) in the paladin and
>   ranger classes. Use this total to determine your spell slots by
>   consulting **Table: Multiclass Spellcaster.**

A level 5 wizard who takes 1 level in Sorcerer has four Level 1 spell slots, three Level 2 slots, and three Level 3 slots, per the multiclass spellcaster table ([visible here](http://www.5esrd.com/classes/)).

If I'm reading the sorcerer class entry correctly, the first level of sorcerer requires that you pick two Level 1 spells ("*You know two 1st-level spells of your choice from the sorcerer spell list.*"), but every sorcerer level taken after the first can allow the character to learn spells of any level he has slots in, including Level 3 spells such as Fireball.

Is my assumption correct?  Can I multiclass into Sorcerer from Wizard and, aside from the initial Level 1 spells known requirement (which can later be swapped with higher level spells per the sorcerer class feature), add spells to my list of Sorcerer Spells Known of any level I have slots in from the multiclass spell slots table?

Comment: related: [Can a multiclass Wizard use any Wizard spell?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50424)

Comment: Possibly a duplicate even? The answer seems to be the same: when multiclassing, "you determine what spells you know and can prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single-classed member of that class".

Comment: Hmm. The title doesn't seem like it, but reading further the questions do seem to each hinge on matching wording in the two different rules…

Comment: Not a duplicate: the Wizard question asks about preparation for a multiclass with two preparation-casters (Cleric and Wizard).

This question is asking whether the spell slots gained from a multiclass of learned and prepared levels would allow, a Prepared X who then levels in a Learned Casting class can Learn spells of the slots they have on the multiclass spellcasting table.

One (lowest rated) answer on the Wizard question sort-of addresses that, but the other's don't and the Wizard question didn't ask for it.

Comment: @RobStening It's a duplicate.  The top-voted and accepted answer on the linked question says, "You determine what spells you know and can prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single-classed member of that class,"  which answers my question.

Comment: Ah, apologies. I overlooked that. The question itself still isn't duplicate, but does happen to be answered in an answer. Okay.